# How to align a circle at the bottom of a div 50% of the circle is inside the div and 50% is outside the div

Tags: css

```
.icon {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: #00CFEF;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 60%;
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, 42%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 42%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0%, 42%);
    -o-transform: translate(0%, 42%);
}
```

The issue is that transform CSS does not align circle in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

`translate` isn't required at all to achieve this. You can use `position: absolute` and `calc()`:

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.circle{
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px);

  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

But you shouldn't try to make it work in all browsers, just in modern browsers. If we continue giving support for old browsers in our applications, people will never feel the need to upgrade to the new ones.